# onItemSelected does not work in updated version 8.0.0

Tags: java, android

I have a list shown in simple spinner. Item is not selected and Onitemselected method is called in Oreo devices. I don't understand why this issue exists in Oreo devices, whereas the everything works fine on all other versions. Can someone help me on this?

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.clear();
    try {
        ArrayList<LeaveApplicationModel.LeaveType> leaveTypeArrayList = LeaveApplicationModel.LeaveType.getLeaveTypeList();

        for (int i = 0; i < leaveTypeArrayList.size(); i++) {
            LeaveApplicationModel.LeaveType leaveType = leaveTypeArrayList.get(i);
            String leaveCode = leaveType.getLeaveTitle();

            list.add(leaveCode);

            LogUtility.printDebugMessage(TAG.concat("setLeaveTypeSpinnerList-list 1-") + list); //NON-NLS
        }

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getContext(), list);
            spinnerDayType.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinnerDayType.setTag(leaveTypeArrayList);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Crashlytics.logException(e);
        LogUtility.printErrorMessage(TAG.concat("setLeaveTypeSpinnerList--") + e); //NON-NLS
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried

Comment: Item is not selected, but OnitemSelected is still called?

Comment: yes, thank you sir..I get solution I add In 
 item layout of recyclerview for android OS 8.0.0 and it works for me 
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"